# gocql.createSession: Consistency level ANY is not supported for this operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, cassandra, gocql, amazon-keyspaces

Getting following error while trying to create session from cql,

```
Error: 
Consistency level ANY is not supported for this operation. Supported consistency levels are: ONE, LOCAL_QUORUM, LOCAL_ONE
```

I've used **Amazon Managed Apache Cassandra Service**

Following is the code for creating session

```
clusterConfig := gocql.NewCluster("<HOST:PORT>")
clusterConfig.Authenticator = gocql.PasswordAuthenticator{Username: "Username", Password: "Password"}
clusterConfig.SslOpts = &gocql.SslOptions{
CaPath: "./AmazonRootCA1.pem",
}
clusterConfig.Consistency = gocql.LocalQuorum
clusterConfig.ConnectTimeout = time.Second * 10
clusterConfig.ProtoVersion = 3
clusterConfig.DisableInitialHostLookup = true
clusterConfig.Keyspace = "TestDB"
clusterConfig.NumConns = 3
session, err := clusterConfig.CreateSession()
if err != nil {
fmt.Println("err>", err)
}
return session
```

I am setting consistency level to **LocalQuorum** but still its giving above mentioned error. If anybody knows how to resolve please help us out

Comment: Try updating your gocql dependency. 17 days ago a related [fix](https://github.com/gocql/gocql/commit/6d895e38b0a53cd804a3a2f547c9d9c0666aef35) was merged to master.

Comment: @mkopriva Doing

Comment: @mkopriva Package upgrade worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package upgrade works for me !